# How to exclude specific dependencies from spring-boot-starter-parent

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, dependency-management

I am using a legacy Spring application and want to migrate to Spring Boot. My intention is to use the `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa`. For this reason I have added following section in `pom.xml` (which manages all `spring-boot-dependencies`):

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
```

But this is screwing up certain dependencies which I need to retain for time being. I am currently using Selenium dependencies (version `2.53.0`; added transitively from another project) but spring-boot is fetching dependencies of `3.9.1`.

I want to exclude `3.9.1` dependencies but the `exclusion` filter is not working as expected.

Just to summarize, I want to use `spring-boot-starter-parent` and `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` but not the managed `selenium-java` from `spring-boot-dependencies`.

Appreciate any help in this regard.

Comment: Just add a `<selenium.version>2.53.0</selenium>` to the `<properties>` tag. This will change the selenium version to the one you want. Don't try to exclude and then include yourself. See https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-customize-dependency-versions

Comment: Sweet! That works when I add the `spring-boot-starter-parent` under parent section. You may want to add this an answer ;) Thanks mate!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Instead of messing around with `<excludes>` and then try to figure out what you need to include again (after figuring out what you excluded). Just override the version as explained [here in the Spring Boot Reference Guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-customize-dependency-versions).

Assuming you are using the `spring-boot-starter-parent` as the parent you can just add a `<selenium.version>` to your `<properties>` section to specify which version you want.

```
<properties>
  <selenium.version>2.53.0</selenium.version>
</properties>
```

This will make Spring Boot use the version you want.

Comment: In my case I have the parent but I want to use spring-boot-starter-webflux, but parent already had spring-boot-starter-web. What can be done here ?

Comment: Will this solution also remove the other version dependency from the .m2 folder?

Answer (score 1):

Mention your dependency in pom.xml which you need to exclude in exclusion tag. Then excluded dependency will not be downloaded:

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>sample.ProjectA</groupId>
      <artifactId>Project-A</artifactId>
      <version>1.0</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion> 
 <!-- declare the exclusion here -->
          <groupId>sample.ProjectB</groupId>
          <artifactId>Project-B</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions> 
    </dependency>
```

Comment: I am aware of how `exclusion` works, but my ask is bit different

Answer (score -1):

Remove the deppendency from the starter pom. Use the exclsuions tag in pom.xml. For example to remove the actuator dependency

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo-1</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>demo-1</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Comment: That won't work. The actuator isn't a dependency from the `spring-boot-starter` so not sure what you are trying to show here..

Comment: I was just giving the example to exclude a dependency from the spring boot starter pom.